# Python3.5 virtual env on Ubuntu 14.04 - error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv set up for both python 2.7 and python3.5 and it was running fine but I have been seeing this issue from today on python3.5 virtual env.

```
(py_35_env)mypc@mypc-Inspiron-3847:/opt/e360/programs/py_35_env/bin$ python
```

I get the following error

```
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here are the files in my bin directory

(py_35_env)mypc@mypc-Inspiron-3847:/opt/e360/programs/py_35_env/bin$ ls -ltr

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mypc mypc 13921 Mar 18 18:43 python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mypc mypc     9 Mar 18 18:43 python3 -> python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mypc mypc     9 Mar 18 18:43 python -> python3.5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mypc mypc  1129 Mar 18 18:43 activate_this.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mypc mypc  2476 Mar 18 18:43 activate.fish
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mypc mypc  1263 Mar 18 18:43 activate.csh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mypc mypc  2207 Mar 18 18:43 activate
```

I added the library path pointing to python on the virtualenv bin directory

```
(py_35_env)mypc@mypc-Inspiron-3847:/opt/e360/programs/py_35_env/bin$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/opt/e360/programs/py_35_env/bin
```

Python3.4 opens fine.

```
(py_35_env)mypc@mypc-Inspiron-3847:/opt/e360/programs/py_35_env/bin$python3.4
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Here is my python where information

```
(py_35_env)mypc@mypc-Inspiron-3847:/opt/e360/programs/py_35_env/bin$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /etc/python3.4 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python3.4m /usr/bin/X11/python3.4 /usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Please suggest how can I fix the error of `error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Is there an error related to symbolic link ? or not pointing to right directory

Comment: any one help please ?

Comment: Did you build the virtualenv on Fedora/Centos/RHEL?

Comment: @Phil it is on Ubuntu 14